# integrate PWA App into Magento2 website

Tags: magento2, module, pwa

I want to integrate PWA App into my Magento2 website , i have already tried with Tigren extension and made changes as per the document. After installation i am getting errors in checkout process.

I am getting the following Errors :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

require.js:1895 GET https://xxxx/pub/static/version1575442910/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/@firebase/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught Error: Script error for: @firebase/app
```

How can i rectify these errors or is there any other way to implement PWA Application

Comment: I have same issue , Have you found any solution for it?